# How do I use PHP after installing Homebrew?

Tags: php, homebrew, macos-monterey

I purchased a new MacBook with MacOS Monterey, so it doesn’t come with PHP installed. I used Homebrew to install PHP, and all went well. But my scripts aren’t executing. The PHP pages run, but they run like regular HTML files. The PHP shows in the source code, and the page is blank.

When I check Homebrew to see which version of PHP is running, it says 8.1.8. Apache is also running properly. Are my files in the wrong place?

I have them in Users/username/Sites/myWebsite as I always have before. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In your terminal navigate to where the .php file you want to execute is and type `php -S localhost:8000` then open your browser go to `localhost:8000`